# Change background color on a ListView's row dynamically with context menu

Tags: android, listview, colors, row

I want to change the color of a single row on a listview.

I have made a custom adapter, and i want change de color on the row's contextual menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {

        case NOTE_BACKGROUND:
            AdapterContextMenuInfo infos = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();


    getListView().getAdapter().getView(infos.position,           null,null).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            notes.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

But it doesn't work... and I don't know why.. Any ideas? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not call `getView()` on Adapter yourself, let `ListView` call it. Also, when you set color on one view, and then scroll the list, same colored view will come again (re-used by `ListView`) for another item.

Use a `Map<Integer,Color>` to store the adapter's item index and color.

Override `getView()` of Adapter, and set color of returned view from this Map.

On Context menu select, put index and color to Map, then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `notifyDataSetChanged`, all the views will be redrawn and the adapter will return new views for the rows. If its a custom adapter, you should have a field in the adapter that stores the index of the row that you want to change the background color for (or something similar) and then returns the correct view accordingly.